# Cannot get latest-version package from multiple yum repos

Tags: rpm, yum, centos8, dnf

There are two rpm repos in my CentOS 8.1.1911. Details are as follows:

```
# virt-1.repo
[appstream]
name=CentOS Linux 8-stream - AppStream
baseurl=http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/centos/8-stream/AppStream/$basearch/os/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

```
# virt-2.repo
[centos-advanced-virtualization]
name=CentOS Linux 8-stream - Advanced Virtualization
baseurl=http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/centos/8-stream/virt/$basearch/advancedvirt-common/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

The two repos both contain the package `libvirt`, and there are newer one in the repo `centos-advanced-virtualization`. My operation is as follows：

1. `yum clean all && yum makecache`
2. `yum list libvirt --showduplicates`, but I get the older one from `appstream`

```
# yum list libvirt --showduplicates
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:18 ago on Sun 26 Sep 2021 05:22:42 PM CST.
Available Packages
libvirt.x86_64                                                 6.0.0-35.module_el8.5.0+746+bbd5d70c                                                 appstream
libvirt.x86_64                                                 6.0.0-36.module_el8.5.0+821+97472045                                                 appstream
```

3. remove appstream, `mv virt-1.repo virt-1.repo.bak && yum makecache`
4. `yum list libvirt --showduplicates`, and I can get the newer one from `centos-advanced-virtualization`

```
# yum list libvirt --showduplicates
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:30 ago on Sun 26 Sep 2021 05:26:08 PM CST.
Available Packages
libvirt.x86_64                                                  7.0.0-9.el8s                                                   centos-advanced-virtualization
libvirt.x86_64                                                  7.0.0-13.el8s                                                  centos-advanced-virtualization
libvirt.x86_64                                                  7.0.0-14.el8s                                                  centos-advanced-virtualization
libvirt.x86_64                                                  7.4.0-1.el8s                                                   centos-advanced-virtualization
libvirt.x86_64                                                  7.5.0-1.el8s                                                   centos-advanced-virtualization
libvirt.x86_64                                                  7.6.0-2.el8s                                                   centos-advanced-virtualization
```

So, why can't I get the newer one at the beginning? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The list of the available versions is sorted in lexical order. Anyway `yum update libvirt` will select the more recent package available (the version `7.6.0-2.el8s` in your example).

By the way, there's no need to remove the `.repo` and create a backup, just set `enabled=0`.

Comment: It does not work for me, this exact issue is happening to me with nginx